# How Can I scrape the Google Keyword Tool?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, keyword

I want to extract data from the Google keyword tool - https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal. Their site is in Javascript, the script I've been working on is in PHP. Anyway to do this?

Alternatively, if there is no good solution, I was thinking of downloading the csv file and extracting data from it. Unfortunately, I've never done something where I download a csv file then extracted data from it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to extract? I'm pretty sure that either google has an API for what you want to achieve or that your script will be blocked before too soon.

Comment: Google adwords has an API, but there was a mass rejection of tokens last week.

Answer (score 2):

Scraping the Keyword tool is not easy (and it breaks the terms and conditions). 
If you download the CSV file you can read it with php (it is a plain text file). You will have to create the logic to use the data in the file.

this will get you started

```
$file_handle = fopen("myfile", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    echo $line;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```